# Get images protected by Access Token in dotnet Maui (alternatives to FFImageLoading)

Tags: c#, maui, ffimageloading

Get images that are protected by Access Token in an api from a Maui dotnet app

Previously for Xamarin FFImageLoading was used

```
ImageService.Instance.Initialize(new Configuration
{
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler
        (_result.AccessToken))
});
```

I need alternative for dotnet Maui

Comment: you probably need to implement your own custom UriImageSource

Comment: You need to implement this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work in MAUI this way.

In your App.Xaml.cs get the service provider

```
public App(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    Services = provider;
}
```

Then you can get the configuration instance and replace HttpClient. You can call this in your custom onstart method

```
var configuration = Services.GetService<IConfiguration>();
    
configuration.HttpClient = new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler('your token here');
```

This is the class that inserts the token

```
public class AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private  readonly Func<Task<string>> _getToken;

    public AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler(Func<Task<string>> getToken)
    {
        _getToken = getToken ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("getToken");
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _getToken.Invoke().Result);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```