How to add custom Http Header to the url when using Maui Image control (Android)
I am migrating my Xamarin Forms app to MAUI. In Xamarin Forms I was using FFImageLoading to cache the images. The Url used in the FFImageLoading was protected by Autorization token, so in the MainActivity.cs, I was able to inject the HttpClient configuration like this:
var ffConfig = new FFImageLoading.Config.Configuration
{
    HttpClient = GetAuthHttpClient(),
    HttpHeadersTimeout = 300
};
FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.Initialize(ffConfig);


The GetAuthHttpClient as follows:

private HttpClient GetAuthHttpClient()
{
    httpClient = new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler(settingsService.GetDeviceToken));
    return httpClient;
}


But for some reason the FFImageLoading doesnt seem to work, so I have decided to use the Image control that comes with MAUI. Unfortunately, I was not able to customize the HttpClient for this either.
Any ideas?
The call to the Http endpoint did not have the Authorization header with the Bearer token in it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550895/get-images-protected-by-access-token-in-dotnet-maui-alternatives-to-ffimageload

@Jason I tried that too, didnt seem to send the headers

For anyone who has this same issue, apparently, there was a bug in the FFImageloading MAUI component, but this is now fixed as of v1.1.8 thanks to microspaze
Customising HttpClient for FFImageLoading.Maui
You can also add any HttpClient customisations in App.xaml.cs as mentioned in the comments above by @Jason
